# Neo4Django - Cannot create node - StatusException thrown

Tags: django, neo4django

Couldn't able to solve it, or couldn't find anything related to this in any mailing list.

Model:

```
class Person(neomodels.NodeModel):
    name = neomodels.StringProperty("Name")
    user_id = neomodels.StringProperty("UserID")
    registered_at = neomodels.DateTimeProperty("Registered At")
```

Django-shell:

```
from models import Person
p = Person.objects.create(name="Metin Emenullahi", user_id="sdg'd;f", registered_at="05/01/2014");
```

Error:

```
StatusException: Code [400]: Bad Request. Bad request syntax or unsupported method.
Invalid data sent: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException.setMaxBufferSize() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Full traceback is [here](https://gist.github.com/mtndesign/7da1812db7fef11d2bdd)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of terrible problem solving process and with agonizing nervous system, I finally figured out why this thing doesn't work:

It is because of the version compatibility between neo4django and neo4j. neo4django has been tested against 1.8.2-1.9.4 versions of neo4j, but I'm using version 2.1.1. I changed it to 1.8.3 (from the version range abbove this is available on the neo4j website), and it worked like a charm.